# unable to get node started following react tutorial

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm following this react tutorial, but I"m afraid it might be a bit outdated, as it was written a couple of years ago. So after creating the files and installing some packages, I tried running the app by starting node and I got this error message.

```
C:\Users\George\Desktop\reactapp>npm start

> reactapp@1.0.0 start C:\Users\George\Desktop\reactapp
> node server.js

module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\George\Desktop\reactapp\server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! reactapp@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactapp@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the reactapp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node server.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs reactapp
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls reactapp
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\George\Desktop\reactapp\npm-debug.log

C:\Users\George\Desktop\reactapp>
```

Comment: "I'm following this react tutorial" — Which tutorial?

Comment: "after creating the files and installing some packages" — What files?

Comment: `Cannot find module 'C:\Users\George\Desktop\reactapp\server.js'` — So that file hasn't been created. What does the tutorial have to say about `server.js`?

Comment: I don't think it mentioned anything about server.js... heres the link to the tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would forego the first way it teaches you because its legacy and spare yourself the frustration as the author does not make clear what versions of `react` or `react-dom` he is installing, so you would have to look at the date of that blogpost and then do your research as to what versions would have been the latest versions back then. Then there is Webpack to deal with, so for all future users of that unmaintained tutorialspoint.com Reactjs tutorial, just follow the CRA steps and ignore the legacy way of building React applications, especially if you are new to Reactjs.

If for whatever reason you wanted to try the legacy way because you want to get your hands dirty with Webpack you can always do a `npm run eject` on the CRA application you created and off you go, configure your heart out with Webpack and Babel.